# switching node version in linux for VS Code installation

Tags: node.js, linux, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, nvm

I'm trying to install VS Code on a Raspberry PI (Pi 3).
I got the Raspberry Pi OS with some pre-installed node application that I want to debug and extend the functionnality.
There for i thought it would be great to have VS Code Server running on the Pi so that i don't have to have the Pi connected to the Internet all the time in order to do the remote-ssh (and this option didn't even work).
The "Blackbox" application that I want to debug / extend the functionnality runs with node `v7.10.0`.
Or at least that's what `node -v` tells me.

I've tried to install nvm in order to switch node versions to be able to install VS Code Server.
I've done the `nvm install 12.0.0` (as VS Code Server says it requires at least node v12) and the `nvm use v12.0.0`. I've tried to use `nvm alias default v12.0.0` aswell, but still if i type `node -v` it gives me the `v7.10.0`. The installation of VS Code server doesn't succeed as it is most probably using the node version installed directly in the linux.

Is there anything i can do in order to have the `node -v` giving out `v12.0.0` so that VS Code can install properly?
VS Code thereafter probably need to use this version (v12.0.0) to operate but the "blackbox" node project still needs to run with node version v7.10.0 (I don't know it it supports anything higher that that).

I thought that `nvm` is controlling the node versions that and that i would be possible to run two different node versions beside each other or at least switch between them.

Is there anything I can do to install VS Code Server?

Comment: If there's any chance of upgrading that node app to a recent even-numbered version of nodejs it would be worth the effort. 7 is very old and odd-numbered versions don't enjoy long-term support anyhow.

Comment: As Already stated, for me it's a "Blaxbox" node app, I would defenetly like to upgrade it but for that i would first need to have VS-Code installed to have a better overview if there are some dependencies, etc. that are bound to some older versions.